# SQLite How to make dynamic creation of tables?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a GPA Calculator using sqlite as the database storage. I can't figure out how to dynamically create new tables, with the name of the tables being based on the user input, this is what I currently have.I want to be able to create a variable that equals the user input, and you can use that variable to constantly change the name of the table.

```
import sqlite3

query = str(input("What do you want to do? (Create Account,Insert New Data) "))

if query.lower() == "create account":
    print("hi")

try:
    insert_parameters = (int(input("ID: ")),str(input("Username:                 ")),str(input("Password:")),float(input("Semester 1 GPA: ")),float(input("Semester 2 GPA: ")))

    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect("SQLite_Python_Test.db")
    sqlite_query_create_table = '''CREATE TABLE gpa_calc_users_test(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
        username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password TEXT NOT NULL,
        gpa_sem1 REAL,
        gpa_sem2 REAL);'''

    sqlite_query_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO gpa_calc_users_test
        (id,username, password, gpa_sem1, gpa_sem2)
        VALUES
        (?,?,?,?,?)
    '''

    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Connected to sqlite Successfully")


    cursor.execute(sqlite_query_create_table)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Table created Successfully")

    cursor.execute(sqlite_query_insert,insert_parameters)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Query inserted Successfully")
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Error while creating a table")

finally:
    if(sqliteConnection):
        sqliteConnection.close()
        print("SQLite connection closed"),

cont = str(input("Do you want to enter another GPA? "))

while(cont.lower() == "yes"):
    try:
        insert_parameters = (int(input("ID: ")),str(input("Username:     ")),str(input("Password:")),float(input("Semester 1 GPA: ")),float(input("Semester 2 GPA: ")))

        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect("SQLite_Python_Test.db")
        sqlite_query_create_table = '''CREATE TABLE gpa_calc_users_test(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
            username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            password TEXT NOT NULL,
            gpa_sem1 REAL,
            gpa_sem2 REAL);'''

        sqlite_query_insert = '''
        INSERT INTO gpa_calc_users_test
            (id,username, password, gpa_sem1, gpa_sem2)
            VALUES
            (?,?,?,?,?)
        '''

        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Connected to sqlite Successfully")

        cursor.execute(sqlite_query_insert,insert_parameters)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Query inserted Successfully")
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while creating a table")

    finally:
        if(sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("SQLite connection closed"),
    cont = str(input("Do you want to enter another GPA? "))
```

Comment: python supports string formatting..
````
query = 'create TABLE {table_name} .....'
query = query.format(table_name=user_input_variable)
````

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63857420/5320906) might help.